# How to use count(*) and Division Operation in SQL statements

Tags: sql

I'm loading big data into database,

i want to know how this process going.

i use

```
select count(*) from table
```

to check how many rows loaded.
and now i want to get a Percentage of the process.
i tried:

```
select ( count(*)/20000 ) from table
```

and

```
select cast(  ( count(*)/20000 )  as DECIMAL(6,4)  ) from table
```

but they all return  0 ,

so how can i do this?

And better if it can show the percentage .

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Integer division returns an integer, the decimal part is truncated. You could divide by `20000.0`:

```
select ( count(*)/20000.0 ) from table
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1fa93/9559/1)</kbd>

[**MSDN** / (Divide)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175009.aspx)

> If an integer dividend is divided by an integer divisor, the result is
>   an integer that has any fractional part of the result truncated.

Answer (score 1):

```
Select CONVERT(DECIMAL(6,4),COUNT(*)) / CONVERT(DECIMAL(6,4),20000) FROM TABLE
```

-
Its important that you match the type explicitly because not all numbers are integers and not all decimals are the same. DECIMAL(6,4) is effectively its own data type which is not the same as DECIMAL(6,3).