# Make one query out of two others?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, subquery

I have never been very good at SQL queries (I've always preferred NoSQL databases, but I need to use a SQL database this time).

I need to research how many seats are sold compared to the amount of total seats in cinema halls. At the moment I can accomplish this using 2 different queries in Hibernate, one for the total amount of seats and the other for the amount of sold seats, and then divising these results.

This is my code :

```
    Double amountOfSoldTickets = ((Long) session.createQuery("select count(*) from Ticket t where t.vertoning.zaal.cinemacomplex.id = :id").
                setInteger("id", complex.getId()).list().get(0)).doubleValue();
    Double capacity= ((Long) session.createQuery("select sum(z.capaciteit) from Zaal z").list().get(0)).doubleValue();
    return amountOfSoldTickets / capacity;
```

I thought about using a subquery though I have no idea how to do this in hibernate.
If anyone has any idea how to solve this in one query it'd be greatly appreciated.

Some additional info: I let hibernate implicitly join my tables in the first query.

`Ticket` has a many to one to `Vertoning`, `Vertoning` has a many to one to `Zaal`, `Zaal` has a many to one to `cinemacomplex`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I encourage you to learn SQL -- and to learn it on a real database instead of through the HQL interface.  HQL is useful for what it does, but it misses on some very important SQL functionality.

I believe the following will work in HQL:

```
select count(*) as SoldSeats,
       (select sum(z.capaciteit) from Zaal z) as Capacity
from Ticket t
where t.vertoning.zaal.cinemacomplex.id = :id;
```

In just MySQL, you could put these as subqueries in the `from` clause:

```
select t.SoldSeats, z.Capacity
from (select count(*) as SoldSeats,
      from Ticket t
      where t.vertoning.zaal.cinemacomplex.id = :id
     ) t
     (select sum(z.capaciteit)  as Capacity
      from Zaal z
     ) z;
```

Note that if this is inside a loop where you are assigning different values to `id`, then the whole loop can possibly replaced with SQL.

Comment: Yes yes I know I should, but honestly, I think NoSQL databases are the future and SQL will be dead in 10 years, so for now I try to avoid using sql unless I absolutely have to

Comment: This query does work however, so I thank you for your help Gordon

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you run this query:

```
Long[] amountOfSoldTicketsToCapacity = 
    ((Long[]) session.createQuery(
        "select count(*), z.capaciteit, z.id " +
        "from Ticket t " +
        "inner join t.vertoning v " +
        "inner join v.zaal z " +
        "inner join z.cinemacomplex c " +
        "where c.id = :id " +
        "group by z.capaciteit, z.id "
        )
        .setInteger("id", complex.getId())
        .uniqueResult());
if {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("There are no tickets sold for Zaal#" + complex.getId());
}       
double capacity = (amountOfSoldTicketsToCapacity.length != 0) ? 
    ((double) amountOfSoldTicketsToCapacity[0]) / amountOfSoldTicketsToCapacity[1] : 0D;
```

Doing the division in Java is simpler, as in SQL you'd probably have to [CAST one operand to NUMERIC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19015652/how-to-use-count-and-division-operation-in-sql-statements).

Comment: This doesn't work, it only takes the capacity of the first Zaal, not all of them

Comment: Added it to the original post

Comment: Great. Then check my updated response. I added a group by clause so that you get all tickets joined by their associated cinema room. You will get an array of 3 longs (the ticket count, the room capacity and the room.id). You are interested in the first two for doing the math. I assumed the Zaal.id is Long, but if it's something else, you should then switch to an Object[] instead.