# count() function cannot be divided in sqlite

Tags: sql, sqlite, count

I am new to SQLite. When I use MySQL, it's reasonable to use `count(*)/5`. However, in SQLite, I try to calculate `count(Name)/5` but the result shows zero.
[image]

[image]

I don't know why this won't work. Is there any way to calculate this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `COUNT` returns an integer, and 5 is an integer. As seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19015652/how-to-use-count-and-division-operation-in-sql-statements): You will have to either cast it, or simply add a decimal to `/5.0`. Now it will no longer be limited to integers.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

If the operands are both integers, SQLite does integer division.  So, just make one operand a float:

```
SELECT COUNT(name)/5. FROM demo
```

Comment: Thank you! It's been a great help!